# Get rid of chrome min font size of 12px when using 62.5% and em design

Tags: css, responsive-design, font-size

When we use 62.5% or 10px as the base unit in a wrapper or the body element then the child nodes can use em unit simpler. 
However, the min font size of chrome being 12px makes the 62.5% design fail. 
if we use 12px as the base unit, it makes the em calculation difficult. 
The way I think of is using 20px as the base unit, then the em units in the inner nodes can be divided the original pixel size by 20. What's the common approach to solve this problem in a responsive design?

Comment: The minimum font size is a _user setting_. That is, your design "fails" on any browser where the user has the minimum font size set to 21px. So the best solution is to not rely on such settings at all, but to just leave the font size as is.

Comment: And I'm not sure why you think this makes your design fail. What kind of calculations are you trying to do? 1.5em is one and a half times the inherited font size, no matter if your base size is 10px or 16px or anything else. Oh, are you worrying about fractional pixels? 1.5em based on a 15 px base size would become 22.5 px?

Answer (score 0):

I personally use rem or "root em" instead of em with a px fallback.  I think it avoids the headache of having to track ems as they cascade.  With rems you can instead style everything relative to the root HTML element (62.5% in your and most common cases).

A nice SASS mixin I utilize is:

```
@mixin font-size($size: 1.6, $line: $size * 1.5) {
    font-size: ($size * 10) + px;
    line-height: ($line * 10) + px;
    font-size: $size + rem;
    line-height: $line + rem;
}
```

Usage is simple:

```
@include font-size(1.4,1.9);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `font-size: 62.5%` for the body if you want correct calculations in all browsers.

Because IE uses his own ClearType fonts, 62.5% is not the same as 10px - its only 9.93px. See Microsoft's answer:

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/816709/ie-11-calculating-font-sizes-wrong-when-setting-the-bodys-font-size-in-relative-units

So assume you have a 1000px-Layout and set body's `font-size` to 62.5% and the layout width to 100em - its only 993px in IE (9.93*100).

400px-Demo (the blue bar is shorter in IE; other browsers are correct):

https://jsfiddle.net/xr77dkLm/

If you set the body's `font-size` to 100% and use 25em width the calculation is correct in this IE-Demo (400px).